# MySQL and time zones

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I run the following SQL:

```
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
INSERT INTO `test` (`stamp`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

The value in `test` is my machine's local time instead of UTC.

According to MySQL [site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html)

> Values for TIMESTAMP columns are converted from the current time zone
>   to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for
>   retrieval.

What am I doing wrong? I want to store my records with UTC date/time stamp and retrieve them in the user's local time zone.

Comment: "I want to store my records with UTC date/time stamp and retrieve them in the user's local time zone." --- if you use timestamp - mysql does that automatically. And you shouldn't care of how date is stored, you just need to go with the fact that it is returned in required timezone

Comment: Which timezone though? I would assume MySQL is using the server's time zone. My users won't be in the same timezone as my server. I guess I don't need to tell MySQL to return values to me in a certain time zone. Instead, I just accept it's in my server's time zone and do the conversions from there?

Comment: Wondering how to do things like this: get all records that are between 3pm and 5pm in user's time zone.

Comment: it doesn't matter what TZ it stores the data, but all the datas retrieved to or got from user are treated as dates in user's timezone (which you specify explicitly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MySQL 5.5 documentation using the TIMESTAMP data type will default to using the server's time zone unless you change the variable from the client side.

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

> Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time
>   zone setting, given by the session time_zone variable. Initially, the
>   session variable takes its value from the global time_zone variable,
>   but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:
>
> mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;

Comment: So, no need to set the timezone. Just use timestamp? Wouldn't it convert from server's time to UTC and UTC to server's time? I need to it to convert from client's time to UTC and UTC to client time (where client time zone is a user specified value in my application).

Comment: I would set the server time_zone to be UTC time then.